# How do I limit the scope of etoolbox environment patching?

Tags: etoolbox, scoping, patching

I want to use the `etoolbox` package to patch a certain environment; but - I only want to do it for a certain stretch of my document.

Enclosing in curly brances doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
{
\AtBeginEnvironment{center}{(patched start!)}
\AtEndEnvironment{center}{(patched end!)}
\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}
}
Out of center.

\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The second environment renders in the patched form as well. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 17):

### Update

The 2020-10-01 release of LaTeX added a new hook mechanism to the LaTeX kernel. `etoolbox` now makes use of that new hook mechanism. This means that the answer provided below no longer works.

All LaTeX hooks are global and there does not appear to be a simple way to make them local. There is a way to add code only for the 'next' use of the hook, which isn't the same as a real local assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\AtNextBeginEnvironment}[1]{%
  \AddToHookNext{env/#1/begin}}

\newrobustcmd{\AtNextEndEnvironment}[1]{%
  \AddToHookNext{env/#1/end}}

\begin{document}
\AtNextBeginEnvironment{center}{(patched start!)}
\AtNextEndEnvironment{center}{(patched end!)}
\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

Out of center.

\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the new LaTeX hooks allow you to remove code from hooks. This wouldn't happen automatically with a closing group, but might be an option depending on your use case.

The following is an attempt at replicating a local hook system by using the global hooks with a local helper macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\LocalAtBeginEnvironment}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{ltbx@local@hook@begin@#1}
    {\AtBeginEnvironment{#1}{\csuse{ltbx@local@hook@begin@#1}}}
    {}%
  \csappto{ltbx@local@hook@begin@#1}}

\newrobustcmd{\LocalAtEndEnvironment}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{ltbx@local@hook@end@#1}
    {\AtEndEnvironment{#1}{\csuse{ltbx@local@hook@end@#1}}}
    {}%
  \csappto{ltbx@local@hook@end@#1}}

\begin{document}
{
\LocalAtBeginEnvironment{center}{(patched start!)}
\LocalAtEndEnvironment{center}{(patched end!)}
\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}
}
Out of center.

\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

### Old answer for LaTeX released before 2020-10-01

`etoolbox`'s document and environment hooks all work globally. Thankfully, the implementation of [`\AtBeginEnvironment`](https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/blob/a1a767a7a10ccccba0963f45fb68ec9dec98de35/etoolbox.sty#L1752-L1753) and [`\AtEndEnvironment`](https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/blob/a1a767a7a10ccccba0963f45fb68ec9dec98de35/etoolbox.sty#L1777-L1778) are very simple so that they can easily be copied and changed to work locally instead of globally.

We just append to the hooks (locally) with [`\csappto`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231291/what-does-csappto-does-and-where-does-it-come-from) and not globally with `\csgappto` as in the original definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\LocalAtBeginEnvironment}[1]{%
  \csappto{@begin@#1@hook}}

\newrobustcmd{\LocalAtEndEnvironment}[1]{%
  \csappto{@end@#1@hook}}

\begin{document}
{
\LocalAtBeginEnvironment{center}{(patched start!)}
\LocalAtEndEnvironment{center}{(patched end!)}
\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}
}
Out of center.

\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX environments map their `\begin{foo}` code to a macro `\foo` and their `\end{foo}` code to a macro `\endfoo`. For most environments you can thus use the classical approach to store the original meaning of a macro using `\let`, and then redefine `\foo` and `\endfoo` (locally) by using the original meaning in the new definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{
% Save the old meaning ...
\let\origcenter=\center
\let\origendcenter=\endcenter
% ... and assign a new one
\def\center{%
    (patch A)%
    \origcenter
    (patch B)%
}%
\def\endcenter{%
    (patch C)%
    \origendcenter
    (patch D)%
}%
\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}
}
Out of centering.

\begin{center}
In center.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

The advantage of this method is that you can easily add material at the start and end, inside and outside the environment, respectively.